# unable to record and save audio in ionic app on IOS

Tags: ios, file, cordova, ionic-framework, media

i am making an ionic app which records the audio and stores it to the persistent location, while it is working perfectly on Android, IOS is making me go crazy.

here is the code i am using

Code for creating directory

```
if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
  console.log('ok..its android. setting base dir path');
  $rootScope.dirBasePath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
} else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
  console.log('it is ios, setting base path');
  $rootScope.dirBasePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
}

console.log($rootScope.dirBasePath);
// create directory for audio recordings
$cordovaFile.createDir($rootScope.dirBasePath, "corrit", false)
.then(function (success) {
  console.log('created dir '+JSON.stringify(success));
}, function (error) {
  console.log('error creating dir '+JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

directory is being created successfully on both platforms

here is the code for recoding audio file

```
timestamp = new Date()
if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
    $scope.audioFileName = timestamp.getTime()+'.amr';
} else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
    $scope.audioFileName = timestamp.getTime()+'.wav';
}
$scope.data.audioSrc = $rootScope.dirBasePath+'corrit/'+$scope.audioFileName;
console.log($scope.data.audioSrc);
$scope.data.media = $cordovaMedia.newMedia($scope.data.audioSrc);

console.log('recording audio...');
$scope.data.media.startRecord();
```

here is the code for playing audio file

```
console.log('stoping audio...');
$scope.data.media.stopRecord();
$scope.data.media.play();
```

here are the console log for ios

```
created dir {"isFile":false,"isDirectory":true,"name":"corrit","fullPath":"/corrit/","filesystem":"<FileSystem: library-nosync>","nativeURL":"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C07AA015-63B3-4B10-8032-08B0352F06F0/Library/NoCloud/corrit/"}

record audio
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C07AA015-63B3-4B10-8032-08B0352F06F0/Library/NoCloud/corrit/1450348328418.wav
recording audio...
THREAD WARNING: ['Media'] took '575.528076' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
exeption nativeEvalAndFetch : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.reject')
stoping audio...
Failed to initialize AVAudioPlayer: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)
THREAD WARNING: ['Media'] took '18.506104' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

my guess is that file is not being record that the specified path

what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: same problem here, I don't know why